# Script to Automatically Delete Empty Rows after Last "Not Empty" Entries in Google Sheet

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script

I am trying to create a script for Google Sheet that will automatically delete the last empty row of the active sheet only. The code is working well , but it does delete raws of another sheet tab and not my active one. Also it does not run automatically and I have to go to the app script panel to force a run each time.

I am looking for a way to run this script automatically to delete all empty rows after the last "not empty" row available on that specific active sheet.

```
//Delete empty rows

function removeEmptyRows() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var allsheets = ss.getSheets();
  for (var s in allsheets){
    var sheet=allsheets[s];
    var maxRows = sheet.getMaxRows(); 
    var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();
    if (maxRows - lastRow > 1){
      sheet.deleteRows(lastRow + 1, maxRows - lastRow);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Does Google code work in Excel?

Comment: Can I ask you about the details of `automatically` of `run this script automatically` you expect? What is the trigger for executing the script?

Comment: It's not exactly what you've asked for but in this blog, I've provided a script to remove all the empty rows and columns from the sheet here: https://medium.com/script-portal/removing-duplicates-in-google-sheets-a-guide-for-non-coders-9389a9fc1c9c. You can modify it to your specifics and setup a time-driven trigger.

Comment: Is your issue resolved, using solution provided below?

Answer (score 0):

According to provided code, to implement functionality to delete the last empty rows of active sheet only, in google sheets, using google apps script, this code can be used.

```
function removeEmptyRows() {
    var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
    var maxRows = sheet.getMaxRows();
    var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();
    if (maxRows - lastRow > 1){
        sheet.deleteRows(lastRow + 1, maxRows - lastRow);
    }
}
```

To make this code run automatically, the trigger, using event source as "Time-driven" can be set in settings "Triggers" for this project in google apps script editor.

Answer (score 0):

Here's your code with out the  loop and set on the active sheet:

```
function removeEmptyRows() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getActiveSheet()
  const maxRows = sh.getMaxRows();
  const lastRow = sh.getLastRow();
  if (maxRows - lastRow > 1) {
    sheet.deleteRows(lastRow + 1, maxRows - lastRow);
  }
}
```